# Make SMS text smaller in code android

Tags: android, html, sms

In my android app I have to send a SMS with customized text like

```
   Material     Price
    Box1       $ 1,500
    Box2       $ 1,700
    Box3       $ 1,800
```

I have made this by using `\t and \n`. But the text size is huge which makes a improper alignment.

Is there any way to make the SMS text smaller.

(Additional Clarification: Also can use a HTML string which makes the above alignment instead of using `\n,\t`.)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where is the text size huge? An SMS does not contain any formatting for text size.

Comment: If there is a large material name comes it goes to second line.